# .htaccess directory exemption

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an Oxwall site in my root directory. It's preventing my subdomain from redirecting to a subdirectory. The directory is a DokuWiki. I am absolutely horrible with RegEx, fyi.

I tried adding a line to my .htaccess, but to no avail

```
RewriteRule ^modpod/ -
```

That failed to provide any change. The address [domain]/modpod/ was still handled with the rest of the .htaccess. If I attempt to use the subdomain, I get a 500 error.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Upon redoubling my search of SOF, and applying a little creativity to an unanswered question, I ended up with a solution.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !modpod/.* [NC]
```

That was added to the beginning of all my Rewrite conditionals. Works perfectly.